# Should I use"$_server document root" or" ..\ "when going b/t folders to access other files?

Tags: php

I was wondering if there's any difference in using:

`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT] . '/path/to/document.html';`

Instead of:

`'../path/to/document.html';`

...assuming they both lead to the same place.

Is there any "best practice" for it or does it not really matter?

Thanks

P.S. How do I accept answers? I didn't know that there was such an option and I look like an idiot with all these unaccepted answers for questions...

Comment: "Assuming they both lead to the same place.... " Well, they might not. So, there.

Comment: To accept an answer, click on the tick next to the one that you want to accept. Sometimes, for users with low rep, there's a delay between asking a question and being able to accept an answer to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really it doesn't matter too much. I would say the best practice is to use the $_Server['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] because that way you know exactly where you are going to end up, whereas if you've got directories nested a few deep, then '..' won't always take you to the same place in different files, so it's just more to keep track of.

You can accept answers by clicking on the check mark next to the up and down arrows to the left of the post that you'd like to accept.

Answer (score 1):

I personally use defined constants, such as follows:

```
define('PATH_BASE', rtrim(strtr(__DIR__, '\\', '/'), '/') . '/');
```

Appending relative paths to `PATH_BASE`:

```
$dir = PATH_BASE . 'path/to/file.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

It's slightly faster to have an absolute path, but I like to stick with the "../" for about 3 levels, and then resort to an absolute path.